# Does echo command automatically add a new line character to the end of the input string?

Tags: bash

So I was just starting learning bash scripting. I encountered a question in a book. 
An example testfile contains following content.

```
$ cat testfile
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
```

And the script file is like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# testing input/output file descriptor
exec 3<> testfile
read line <&3
echo "Read: $line"
echo "This is a test line" >&3
```

After running the script, the testfile became:

```
$ cat testfile
This is the first line.
This is a test line
ine.
This is the third line.
```

I understand why that script changes the testfile. My question is why 
"ine." starts from a new line? Does echo command automatically add a newline character to the end of the string?

Comment: Have a look at `help echo`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`echo -n` is what you seek: the option -n
 instructs echo to "do not output the trailing newline".

FWIW: `man echo` on your platform will instruct what options the /bin/echo command understands. But since you mention bash as shell: bash has an internal implementation of echo (a so-called "builtin")